# Usage of "a" and "the" and their difference

Tags: grammar

Should I use **a** or **the** in the following context?

- Yesterday, I lost **a/the** book that John gave me.

Note that John gave me 3 books.

Answer (score 1):

> Yesterday, I lost **a** book that John gave me.

That sentence would be both true and grammatical.

> Yesterday, I lost **one of the books** that John gave me.

That sentence is also true and grammatical, and it adds some additional information (namely, that John gave you more than one book).

> Yesterday, I lost **the** book that John gave me.

That sentence is grammatical, but it could be considered a little misleading, because it makes it sound like John gave you only one book.

---

To add one extra wrinkle, consider this:

> Yesterday I lost the book, **which** John gave me.

One could argue that this is a valid sentence, too. We use "the book" because we are talking about one lost book, and we add a non-restrictive clause to mention that the lost book was from John.

More information about *that* vs. *which* and non-restrictive clauses can be found by Googling `that vs. which`, but I will put in just one example, which I found in a [Grammarly blog](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/which-vs-that/):

> A defining clause (also called an essential clause or a restrictive clause) gives information essential to the meaning of the sentence. ***That*** is used in defining clauses. Here’s an example:
>
> > *My bike that has a broken seat is in the garage.*
>
> In this sentence, you understand that the speaker has at least one other bike. Specifically, the bike he’s talking about is distinguished from his other bikes by its broken seat. If you removed the clause “that has a broken seat,” you would lose the implication that he owns more than one bicycle, and even if you somehow knew about the other bikes, you wouldn’t know which one was in the garage.
>
> ***Which*** introduces non-defining clauses. Unlike defining clauses, non-defining clauses (also called nonessential or nonrestrictive clauses) don’t limit the meaning of the sentence. You might lose interesting details if you remove them, but the meaning of the sentence wouldn’t change. Sometimes, these phrases are set off by commas.
>
> > My bike, which has a broken seat, is in the garage.
>
> Here, the broken seat seat is simply a description of the bike in the garage. There’s no implication that the speaker owns more than one bike.

It's worth pointing out that many native speakers use *that* and *which* just about interchangeably in sentences like this, particularly in conversation. As [one website](http://www.kentlaw.edu/academics/lrw/grinker/LwtaThat_Versus_Which.htm) says:

> The traditional approach is to use "that" with restrictive clauses and "which" with nonrestrictive clauses. While some writers seem to have abandoned the distinction entirely, no better rule has come along to replace the traditional rule.